Why won't the >= operator work properly in Python?
In my code (enough_beakers = {beakers_per_kid >= 5}) from a tutorial, the ">=" operator is listed as "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'set' and 'int'". Can someone explain to me what this means?
I have tried different fixes, such as removing the thing that is trying to be printed with it to test, as well as trying to change the variable it is connected to and how it uses its equation (safety_glasses_per_kid = {safety_glasses / kids}), but it hasn't worked.

safety_glasses_per_kid = {safety_glasses / kids} assigns a set with one element from the result of safety_glasses / kids to safety_glasses_per_kid, and that is a set so it isn't a number that you can compare with another number. You should remove the { and } if you don't want to enclose the result into a set.

Please, take some time to read how to ask and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@metatoaster Thank you. I tried the adjustment, and it fixed the problem =D
